# Accessing input.val() at client side in order to render partial with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an input with id "searcha", trying to perform a live search

```
    <input type="input" id="searcha" placeholder="Search">
```

I can't find a way to pass the $('#searcha').val() to render on keyup()

```
 $('#searcha').keyup(function(){
 $('#index-table').html('<%= j (render index, :locals => query: $('#searcha').val() ) %>')
  })
```

and How should I be passing params[:query] to the controller ?

Comment: Looks like you are missing the # at searcha in the second line, by the way, you could replace it with the keyword ```this```

Comment: I wrote that here as an example of what I meant, it would'nt work anyway. because:  `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name.